# Why "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)"?

Tags: c++

So, I keep receiving the

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is
> 0)

message when I try to run my code. What I'm trying to do is to make it so that it outputs the double stored between the first curly brace and the comma in the nm_1 variable. (*sorry if my code is a bit messy, it's late)

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string funct;
    
    std::cout << "-->";
    std::cin >> funct;
    
    if (funct.find("math") != std::string::npos) {
        int bracket_pos_1 = funct.find("{");
        int bracket_pos_2 = funct.find("}");
        int temp = 0;
        // int temp_2 = 0;
        std::string nm_1;
        std::string nm_2;
        auto split_string = funct.substr(bracket_pos_1 + 1, bracket_pos_2 - bracket_pos_1  - 1);
        // string ss = split_string;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i) {
            std::string nm_1;
            string ss = split_string;
            if (ss.at(temp) == '0' || ss.at(temp) == '1' || 
                ss.at(temp) == '2' || ss.at(temp) == '3' || 
                ss.at(temp) == '4' || ss.at(temp) == '5' || 
                ss.at(temp) == '6' || ss.at(temp) == '7' ||         
                ss.at(temp) == '8' || ss.at(temp) == '9') {
                nm_1.at(temp) = ss.at(temp);
            } 
            else if (ss.at(temp) == '.') {
                nm_1.at(temp) = ss.at(temp);
                i++;
            }
            else if (ss.at(temp) == ',') {
               i = 2;
            }

            temp++; 
        }
            
        nm_1.at(temp - 1) = '0';
        // std::cout << split_string;
        cout << endl << endl << nm_1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you read the message `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)`, *what do you think it means*? What specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: You called `.at` with an index greater than the length of a string. I suggest you load up a debugger and figure out *which* the many, many `.at` calls on strings is failing.

Comment: Maybe you should print `ss` and see what's in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is this:

```cpp
std::string nm_1;
nm_1.at(temp) = ...
```

You can't overwrite characters that don't exist in the string. You should rather append to the string. The easiest would be using `+=` operator:

```cpp
nm_1 += ...
```

The second problem is with this:

```cpp
std::string nm_1;
for (...) {
    std::string nm_1;
    nm_1 += ...
```

Any modification you do to `nm_1` will happen to that variable inside the loop. The problem is that this variable is destroyed at the end of one iteration and created anew at the beginning of the next iteration, so all your modification done inside the loop are lost. Just remove that variable definition to fix it:

```cpp
std::string nm_1;
for (...) {
    nm_1 += ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) member function will throw an exception if you try and access elements that are out-of-bounds. Your `std::string nm_1` is empty by default (contains no elements). If you call `nm_1.at(x)` and supply any index at all, it will always throw, because there are no elements. This applies even if you are attempting to put elements into the string.

If you want to add characters to the end of a string, you can use [`nm_1.push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) member function. Alternatively, if you know the desired length of the output, you can use [`.resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) in advance, and then you will be able to use `.at()` accordingly (the `.resize()` method lets you choose what character to fill the string with, by default it is the null character).

Also, you declare `std::string nm_1` twice, once outside the loop, and once inside the loop. The declaration inside the loop "shadows" the one outside the loop. Basically, this means any time you refer to `nm_1` inside the loop, the one declared outside the loop will remain unaffected.